# Drupal images wont show after moving to another server

Tags: php, image, drupal, server

When i moved to another server, the drupal images that are in /sites/default/files wont show, the folder has 755 permisions (tried 777 too) the path is correct in file system, when edit the block and reselect the image from server it shows perfectly

when the image is not showing the path is:

"/sites/default/files/Boton_Carteleras_0.jpg"

when the image is reselected the path is:

"/inderweb/sites/default/files//Boton_Carteleras_0.jpg"

Comment: This is exactly what the [Pathologic module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your `settings.php` if you have a `base_url` variable and change it. It should fixes your problem.

Comment: $base_url = 'http://192.168.0.162/inderweb'; 

192.168.0.162 its the server (it was localhost), but can't make the images appear